# Finding order of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ with just the very basics

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

In my Abstract Algebra class, our professor just introduced the concepts of groups to us, and one of the problems on our homework assignment is to compute the order of the automorphism group $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$. I've been searching online and in books how to do this, because our professor did not tell us. What I have found is that most of the time this is done by applying one of many theorems, including using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is cyclic (**We haven't learned what a cyclic group is yet.**), that it's isomorphic to $U_{3}$ (**We haven't learned yet how that even helps**).

Basically, it looks like I have to do this by using the proverbial "stone knives and bear skins". I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is an additive group, consisting of the elements $\{0, 1, 2\}$, and that an automorphism is a bijective map from a group to itself that preserves the group structure. So, I suppose the identity map that would map $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ to itself would work. **But, how do I list out what all the possible bijective homomorphisms from $\mathbf{\mathbb{Z}_{3}}$  to itself without using any slick tools?** There must be a lot of them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you know about the image of $0$ under a group homomorphism?

Do you know how many bijective maps exist on a $3$-element set?

Can you combine this knowledge to narrow down the possibilities? Do you know how to check those possibilities?

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable answer. I suspect this question was asked because $\Bbb Z_3$ is a small enough group that you can "play around" with the bijections, and try to figure out which ones are automorphisms by hand.

Comment: @JessyCatI disagree, it's not a comment. I'm not asking for details to help understand the question. I'm telling you what to investigate in order to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @ChrisCulter, okay,  but we never proved any results about this stuff, so I'm not sure what I'm allowed to use  at this point and what I'm not. There's also no textbook. Just our lectures and some printed out notes our prof gives us.

Comment: Then you can look at some homomorphisms that you've seen before. Can you find at least two examples, hopefully in the lecture notes? What did those homomorphisms do with the identity? Can you form a conjecture about how general this behavior is? Does the definition of a homomorphism help you to prove or disprove your conjecture?

Comment: @ChrisCulter, first I need to eat food. Then, I'll take a look at this more closely and see if I can figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisCulter, okay. So, I am still working on this, and this is what I have come up with: We were taught a result that said that the set of all bijections on a set $X$, $f: X\to X $ form a group called the full symmetry group of $X$: $\text{Sym}(X) = \{ f \in X^{X} | f\,\text{is a bijection.} \}$. So, letting $X=\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ is a permutation group on the $3$ elements $0,1,2$. So, I (continued in next comment)...

Comment: have that there are $3! = 6$ elements in $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$, and then must determine which of these bijections are homormorphisms.  Listed out, the bijections are $e = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, what I did was the following (continued in next comment)...

Comment: for $f_{1}(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $f_{2}(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $f_{3}(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $f_{4}(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, (continued in next comment)...

Comment: $f_{5}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1& 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $f_{6}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$,, I checked whether $f_{i}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \right) = f_{i}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} f_{i}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\  0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$. (continued in next comment)...

Comment: @ChrisCulter, however, I don't think that was the correct approach. Because when I did this, I got that only $f_{1}$ was a homomorphism, and from the other guy's answer above, I was under the impression that two of them should turn out to be homormorphisms.  Therefore, my question for you is, instead, for each of the bijections, for example, for $f_{2}$, should I instead do the following:  e.g. $f(2 + 0) = f(2) \mapsto 1$ and $f(2) + f(0) \mapsto 1 + 0 = 1$, and then check that for every possible pairing $(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)$ under each map $f_{i}$?

Comment: @JessyCat I think you're confusing which group you're looking at. Your $f_i$ seem to be defined as *functions* $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})\to \text{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$, and you're checking whether each $f_i$ is a homomorphism. But the original question was about *elements* of $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$. Is $e = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ itself a homomorphism? What about the other five permutations?

Comment: @ChrisCulter, oooooh. So do check each element under these permutations...

Comment: @ChrisCulter, I figured it out! Only $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are homomorphisms. So, the order of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ is $2$. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma.** Let $G$ and $G'$ be two groups. Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow G'$ be a group morphism. One has: $$\varphi(1_G)=1_{G'}.$$

**Proof.** One has: $$\varphi(1_G)=\varphi(1_G\times 1_G)=\varphi(1_G)^2.$$
Right-composing the equality by $\varphi(1_G)^{-1}$ leads to the result. $\Box$

Therefore, an element of $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ must send $\overline{0}$ to $\overline{0}$. Then, you are free to send $\overline{1}$ on $\overline{1}$ or $\overline{2}$, otherwise the map won't be bijective. Afterward, check that the two constructed maps are morphisms.